# Simplest build of QMYSQL3

Tags: qt, qt4

What is simplest way to build the QMYSQL3 driver with the full 4.6 SDK (2009.05) installed? Does the resulting DLL require a manual copy in order for the SDK to use it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have not installed mysql driver at

```
$QTDIR/plugins/src/sqldriver/mysql
```

than install it with

```
qmake -o Makefile INCLUDEPATH+="mysql header files path" LIBS+="mysql library path -L lmysqlclient" mysql.pro
make
```

If you can't able to load the driver, than reconfigure QT with

```
./configure -qt-sql mysql
```

and specify header file path and library path with -I and -L option.